# Updating Chart.js chart in real-time with new data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript

so I am using chart.js to display my data . so the problem now is I want the chart to update automatically when new data is entered like in real without reloading the page.  so each time I enter new data , i have to reload the page in order for the chart to be able to update. I want my chart to update without reloading the page, like real time[image]